# Is there a way to backup Python modules?

Tags: python, linux, module, backup, linux-mint

Is there a way to backup Python modules? I installed lots of modules. If my system does not work properly, I will lose them all. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: What do you want to achieve precisely? Do you want to save the content of the modules? i.e. save the files? Or do you need to save a list of all installed modules so that you can get your configuration back as quick as possible in case you have to reinstall? Did you install all modules through mint's packet manager or are you also talking about your own modules or installed with pip?

Comment: next time you setup your python environment give a try to [Virtualenv](http://www.virtualenv.org/en/latest/virtualenv.html#usage) with this tool you can have separated environments that can be ported and updated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you installed them with pip, you can use `pip freeze` to list the currently installed modules. Save this to a file and use `pip install -r file` on a new system to install the modules from the file.

Comment: Thank you. However, does it not work if I have installed modules via easy_install?

Comment: I don't think easy_install has an equivalent command, but you can always take a backup of your `site-packages` directory

Comment: It seems I'm getting through, yet I want to ask: Where is site-packages directory in Linux? :D (Linux Mint 15)

Comment: I'm sorry. I have just solved my problem. It seems pip module listing works nicely with all modules which are even installed by other tools. Thank you again. :)